# How to query wp_usermeta using WordPress inbuilt functions efficiently?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to query wp_usermeta table to retrieve some meta datas of the users using WordPress built in functions..how can I do it? I don't want to use direct mysql queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get all user id using $users = get_users($args);
  $args define argument."https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users".

After use get_user_meta() which is here "https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta".

now problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a class, WP_User_Query, that handles that.

For example if you wanted to query it for a custom field like "Country" and get all users from Japan:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'country', 'meta_value' => 'Japan' ) );
```

The reference can be found at https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query

Comment: That's a nice answer. But I'm having around 100 users in the table ,how can I fetch the user metas of all the users based on their ids.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get from the table? Be specific.

Comment: I want to get meta value with respect to meta key for all the users.

Comment: you would add 'order_by' => 'ID', order => 'ASC' to the array.

Read over that reference. It will get you going.